# Program Crashes on NULL Pointer object

Tags: c++

I am trying a code which Goes like this:-

```
class test{ 
 int test_int;
 public:
    virtual int show()
    {
        return test_int;
    }
    void set_int(int data){
        std::cout<<"received data "<< data <<endl;
        test_int = data;
    }

};
int main()
{
    test *ptr=new test();
    ptr=NULL;
    ptr->set_int(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the problem i am facing is my program after printing the data which i am sending through set_int function got printed but the program crashes just after the completition of the function(set_int).

Am i doing any mistake that is not according to the language standards?
TIA.

Comment: `ptr=NULL;` is probably a bad move ....

Comment: Yes, you're specifically calling a method on a NULL pointer. You're also leaking the new object when you reassign the pointer to NULL. Don't do it: the leak is bad and the call is illegal.

Comment: @RogerRowland yes, it must be `ptr=nullptr` :)

Comment: @Yola: no, it must be `shared_ptr<test>::reset()`.

Comment: @Useless but i have not allocacted space t the object just a pointer it is.

Comment: When you write `new`, you create a new object. Space is allocated, and any necessary construction is done. In this case you then immediately discarded the new object and reassigned your pointer to an address which can't contain a valid object, before calling a method on an object which doesn't exist. I honestly don't know what is confusing you, or what you expected to happen, but I think we're in _read a good book or online reference_ territory.

Answer (score 4):

> Am i doing any mistake that is not according to the language standards?

Yes, you are.

You may not call member functions on a pointer that does not point to a valid object of that type. A null pointer never points to a valid object.

The trivial fix here is to remove the line `ptr=NULL;`. That way `ptr` still points to an object when the member function is invoked. This also allows you to fix the memory leak by deleting the pointer later. As a sidenote: avoid manual memory management.

Answer (score 3):

You have pointer to `test` (`test*`) set to dynamicaly allocated memory representing instance of that class.
Right after that, you wrote "Nah, I do not need it anymore" and you forget where that newly allocated memory was.
Finally, you are trying to access an object on address `0`, which is an invalid operation and will cause runtime error.

You probably meant to do this

```
int main()
{
    test *ptr = new test();
    ptr->set_int(5);
    // ptr = NULL; // wont free the memory allocated by new
    delete ptr; // memory deallocation
    ptr = NULL; // now we can safely forget that address (which is now invalid anyways)
    return 0;
}
```